# FACETS only on the documents returned in SOLR 5.0

Tags: solr, pagination, facet

So I am using pagination which give me only 20 results at a time. But there are around 10K matching documents, with 7K facets. All of these 7K facets are returned.

I need a way only those facets should be returned that are present in 20 results.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is not part of vanilla Solr functionality. You can emulate the behaviour by making two calls: One to get the 20 documents, one to get the proper facets. To query for the facets, extract the IDs of the 20 documents from the first result and create a single query with all the IDs OR'ed together.